# Back button on browser doesn't refresh content/send requests for new data

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have a React frontend Django backend app which is basically like a feed (ex: Instagram, Facebook).

When the user loads the feed, a request is sent to my backend API which will return the information for the posts displayed on the feed. When the user clicks on a post, they are directed to a separate page showing only that post; this separate page makes a request to my backend API which returns the information for that post only. There is a "like" button for each post (ex: heart for Instagram posts), which sends a request to my backend API to add the post to the user's list of liked posts. If a user clicks "like", the heart should be filled in.

After the following steps:

1. user goes to the feed
2. user clicks on a post and is taken to a page with only that post
3. user clicks "like"
4. user clicks back button in the browser to go back to the feed

I want the post to show that it has been liked. However, since the back button doesn't send new requests to my backend API to get the data for the feed, the post doesn't show that it's been liked. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How are you handling state? Using redux or locally in the component?

Comment: Locally in the component.